# NodeJS pg doesn't update table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I'm using Node's pg package to update my postgresql table and it doesn't do anything. JS code:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
var rquid = '0977ae77939c4ce58596b26b8de8ddcd'
var updateClient = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'pao',
    password: '1q2w3e4R%',
    port: 5432,
});
var updateQuery = `UPDATE pao SET status = 'old' WHERE rquid = '`+rquid+`';`;
updateClient.query(updateQuery, (err, res) => {
        console.log(err, res)
        updateClient.end();
});
console.log(updateQuery)
```

The 'status' value doesn't change?

Comment: Aren't you getting any errors?

Comment: You've never [connected your client](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#clientconnect).

Comment: @Bergi just noticed this, my bad sorry

Comment: If this isn't calling the callback with an informative error though, I'd recommend to file an issue with the library - mistakes can happen, but "*doesn't do anything*" shouldn't